# Android ListView constantly reloading image elements imported from firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-storage

In an android app I have made, the home page shows a list a games in a listview, each row being custom made to include a textview and an imageview and some buttons. The imageview's src comes from downloading th image from my google cloud firebase, and the functionality of this works well, but when the listview is scrolled through there is an issue. The images seem to be unloaded when scrolled away from, which causes a bit of lag when they are reloaded once scrolled back to. I imagine this is built in to prevent a listview from loading many high resolution images and keeping them loaded, but for my list, keeping the images loaded won't be a problem. Is there a way I can turn this off and just keep the images loaded? Here is a video of the problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYYJWZcvBy4&feature=youtu.be

here is the code of the listview and getting the image from firebase:

```
public void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    TextView toolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle);
    toolbarTitle.setText("Popular Games");

    ArrayList<GameInformation> PopularGames = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.child("Games").getChildren().iterator();
    PopularGames.clear();
    while(items.hasNext()){
        GameInformation game = new GameInformation();
        DataSnapshot item = items.next();
        game.setGameName(item.child("Name").getValue(String.class));
        game.setActiveLobbies(Integer.parseInt(item.child("Live Lobbies").getValue().toString()));
        game.setPicturePath(item.child("FilePathName").getValue().toString());

        Iterator<DataSnapshot> itemsDeep1 = item.child("consoles").getChildren().iterator();
        while(itemsDeep1.hasNext()){
            DataSnapshot itemDeep = itemsDeep1.next();
            game.setConsoles(itemDeep.getValue(String.class));
        }

        Iterator<DataSnapshot> itemsDeep2 = item.child("genres").getChildren().iterator();
        while(itemsDeep2.hasNext()){
            DataSnapshot itemDeep = itemsDeep2.next();
            game.setGenres(itemDeep.getValue(String.class));
        }

        if (game.getActiveLobbies() == 1){
            PopularGames.add(game);
        }

    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Hello Here" + PopularGames.size());
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, PopularGames);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

getting the image:

```
storageRef.child("Games/"+singleGame.getPicturePath()+".jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Glide.with(getContext()).load(uri).into(gameImageID);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay you're facing is because there are 2 operations (each one takes a few secs to complete) being performed when you get each image:

1. The image is read from Firebase Storage using `getDownloadUrl()`
2. The image is displayed with Glide

I recommend that when you store the images, save their Download URL to the database instead of saving their path. This way, you'd no longer need to call for `getDownloadURL()`. You'd simply load the image with a single operation:

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(singleGame.getPicturePath()).into(gameImageID);
```

---

Not related to the question:

You can simplify your code by using a `forEach` loop (instead of `while`) in your Iterators:

```
PopularGames.clear();
for(DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.child("Games").getChildren()){
    GameInformation game = new GameInformation();
    game.setGameName(item.child("Name").getValue(String.class));
    game.setActiveLobbies(Integer.parseInt(item.child("Live Lobbies").getValue().toString()));
    game.setPicturePath(item.child("FilePathName").getValue().toString());

    for(DataSnapshot itemDeep: item.child("consoles").getChildren()){
        game.setConsoles(itemDeep.getValue(String.class));
    }

    for(DataSnapshot itemDeep: item.child("genres").getChildren()){
        game.setGenres(itemDeep.getValue(String.class));
    }

    if (game.getActiveLobbies() == 1){
        PopularGames.add(game);
    }

}
Log.d(TAG, "Hello Here" + PopularGames.size());
```

Comment: this helps me with load times, thank you. But do you have any idea why the images keep loading repeatedly? Take instagram for example, it will keep the images within scrolling distance loaded so there is no need to completely load in again.

Comment: I believe a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) can do that. You might want to replace your ListView with that